# What is the basic concept used to verify emails on websites?

Tags: javascript, html, url, velo

**Problem:**
I'm trying to build a website on Wix.com and one of my features is email verification.

**Background:**
My current process is that the user registers which takes them to *[www.abc.com/example?id=12345](http://www.abc.com/example?id=12345)* where 12345 is the random number generated by the database that is individual to each row in the database.

The user then gets an email with the url *[www.abc.com/verify?id=12345](http://www.abc.com/verify?id=12345)* to open to verify their account.

As you can probably see this is extremely unsecure as someone can do this process once and figure out how to create accounts in someone elses name.

**Question:**
What is the standard industry approach to this?
My current idea is to use a second url query that the user does not have access to and so cant guess or work out but I'm struggling to think of what that would be

Comment: Sorry I'm somewhat new to this whole area, what do hashing and salting mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "industry standard" for doing this. There are many innovative ways to do so. In short - if it works, it works.

The most common approach usually involves

- Generating a random code
- Storing that code in a database
- When a request is made to verify their email address, search the database for the code. If it exists, you can mark the user whom the code belongs to as verified

This is pretty simple to do. It seems to me like you are getting stuck at the "Generating a random code" part.

There are 2 basic approaches to do this.

**1)** Generate a random number

**2)** Salt the email address

## Generate a random number

You can generate a random number that acts as a code. This can be done by the following:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int n = 100000 + rnd.nextInt(900000);
```

Which generates a random 6 digit number. It can be tweaked to accommodate for higher numbers. The problem with this method is that if you are dealing with a large userbase, it is likely that randomly generated numbers will start running out. You will have to add verification methods to ensure that the generated code has not already be used.

## Salt the email address

This is the most simple method to do. All you need to do is make sure that there can be no duplicate accounts with the same email.

For starters, you need the user's email address, and their register date (for salting). You can concatenate the two strings, then perform a cryptographic hash. If you don't know how to perform one, just go [here](https://www.baeldung.com/sha-256-hashing-java).

The benefit of this is, there is infinite possible combinations for a code.

Example:

Let's assume that my email was `notmyaddressbutstilldarngood@domain.nice` and the `System.currentTimeMillis()` returned `1605486656`, you would be hashing `notmyaddressbutstilldarngood@domain.nice1605486656`, which returns `95e3dde92f8bb07e43b77c085f1ff2f166e1b9426f9b2f7a685171f4cd66b39c`. So your website link would be

```
www.abc.com/verify?id=95e3dde92f8bb07e43b77c085f1ff2f166e1b9426f9b2f7a685171f4cd66b39c
```